# Entity Framework 6 full text search

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use full text search in Entity Framework 6. I've found a library https://www.nuget.org/packages/EfFts/ and it works but I need call CONTAINS function on two columns with OR not AND:

WHERE CONTAINS(title, 'test') OR CONTAINS(content, 'test')

but I really don't know how to force EF to create such a query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like?

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntityType>("select * from table WHERE CONTAINS(title, {0}) OR CONTAINS(content, {1})", param1, param2);
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot do this because I use Include